# HA -heartbeat and webserver

Tags: linux, web-services, centos, high-availability, heartbeat

**I'm using hearbeat 2.1.4 2 nodes work properly but when i stop httpd in node1 manually heartbeat does not switch to node02. how to fix this problem ??
**

Comment: Now let me check my crystall ball.. or perhaps you want to provide the configuration files and proof that heartbeat is running?

Comment: i done lab via [http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=heartbeat&f=1](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_5&p=heartbeat&f=1)

Answer (score 1):

That version of Hearbeat doesn't monitor the services. It's more intended to be used as hardware failover. You can switch to Heartbeat+Pacemaker or you can use an external tools (I use Mon) to monitor your service and to stop Heartbeat if it fails. When Heartbeat stop, the services will be moved to the other server.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a tutorial that configures heartbeat to work *with apache*.

note: untested hit from google: http://www.novell.com/communities/node/3857/setting-heartbeat-apache-high-availability-sles-10